# Function-Database Help

Tags: php, database, function, forms, joomla

I am using an extension for Joomla! called Breezing Forms.
I can add custom functions (php) to the form, I need to do the following things:

1) If I have a dropdown list with cities-

eg: New York, Los Angeles, Miami
and each city has its own value
eg: 1, 2, 3

I have two rows in a database table, one for the id, and one for the actual city name.
What kind of function do I need to make to just select one value from a list in a form, but populate both rows like above?

2) How can I have the value of one text field in a form be the same for two rows in a table?

3) What function do I need to pass the date (in Y-m-d format) to a row?

Thanks for any help! I'm not too good with PHP code, I'm more of a designer.

Comment: Why are the city IDs and names being stored in separate rows? It would be a lot easier for you to store them in pairs, if you have any control over this - such as (1, New York), (2, Los Angeles).

Comment: The database is already made and if I know enough, I might be able to do that, but it's beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean columns and not rows? And do you want to know how to connect IDs with names? If so, you will need to use [SQL JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). For example, cities table:

```
city_id, city_name
1, 'New York',
2, 'Chicago',
3, 'Los Angeles'
```

And a user table with city IDs

```
user_id, name, city_id
1, 'test', 1,
2, 'jdoe', 3
```

Now, you can use a join on this.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.name, c.city_name
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON c.city_id = u.city_id
```

I don't know what mean by question 2, but you can use the date() PHP function to pull specific dates.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, how would I implement this? If a user completes the form, will the database know to assign a name to a column based on the id of another column? 

And which PHP function specifically do I use? I tried <?php echo date ("Y-m-d"); ?>